# React Admin - Redirecting to a page after login

Tags: react-router, react-admin

I have a react admin application with a customRoutes, as well as resources (say /users). One of my custom route is a private page (say /private), which I protect with the useAuthenticated() hook:

```
export default () => {
    useAuthenticated();
    return (<Card>
        <Title title="Private Page" />
        <CardContent>
            This is a private page.
        </CardContent>
    </Card>)
}
```

When I browse this private page and I'm not authenticated, I'm entering an authentication process as it should be (I'm using OIDC). This process is triggered by the checkAuth() method of the authProvider. But when the process is completed, I'm redirected to the /users resource and not the /private page. Is there a way to tell the authProvider that I want to be redirected to the private page?

Thanks - C

Answer (score 1):

I have not done this myself, but I imagine you can use your redirect path as an argument in the useAuthenticated() call. https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Authentication.html#useauthenticated-hook

```
export default () => {
  useAuthenticated({ redirectPath: '/privatepage' });
  return (
    <Card>
      <Title title="Private Page" />
      <CardContent>
        This is a private page.
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
  )
}
```

From there you should be able to use that arg/parameter in your checkAuth method.

Comment: Hi, thanks or the answer. I had actually tried this - but once you are in the checkAuth, how do you do a redirect to the page? It is not very clear from the Marmelab doc. Thanks - C

Comment: I would try the useRedirect hook. They have an example in the dataProvider: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Actions.html#handling-side-effects-in-usedataprovider

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr In your login().then() aspect, do a redirect('/myDefaultUrl')

I had the same challenge as you, I think. After looking into the ReactAdmin code a bit I was unable to find a way to do it in any 'official' way. I did see something quite interesting in the useAuthProvider() hook.

The AuthProvider object maintained by RA seems to have a variable with a couple properties initialized with some defaults.

```
import { useContext } from 'react';

import { AuthProvider } from '../types';
import AuthContext from './AuthContext';

export const defaultAuthParams = {
    loginUrl: '/login',
    afterLoginUrl: '/',
};

/**
 * Get the authProvider stored in the context
 */
const useAuthProvider = (): AuthProvider => useContext(AuthContext);

export default useAuthProvider;
```

Specifically the afterLoginUrl property looked interesting. I attempted to override that property in my authProvider but didn't have any luck.

What I ended up doing was this.  In my invocation of the login (from useLogin()), when the authProvider.login resolves, I return back the user along with their profile (I use Cognito so it is a CognitoUser instance).  In my user I have configured an attribute for where the user should go after login. I then simply use the redirect hook (from useRedirect) to then direct the user to that URL.

Here is my login from my AuthProvider:

```
const authProvider = {
  login: (params) => { 
      if (params instanceof CognitoUser) {
          return params;
      }
      if (params.error) {
          return Promise.reject(params.error);
      }        
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          Auth.signIn(params.username,params.password).then(cognitoUser => {
              if (cognitoUser.challengeName === 'NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED') {
                  reject({ code: 'NewPasswordRequired', cognitoUser: cognitoUser })
              } else {
                  setAndStoreUserProfile(cognitoUser);                    
                  resolve(cognitoUser); 
              }
          }, function(err) {
              reject(err);
          });
      });
  },
....
```

Then in my Login form, I do this:

```
raLogin(formData)
                .then((cognitoUser) => {   
                    console.log("User logged in. Result:", cognitoUser);
                    clearTransitionState();
                    redirect('/profile');
                })
                .catch(error => {        
                    if (error.code && error.code === 'PasswordResetRequiredException') {
                        transition(PHASE.RESET_ACCOUNT, {username: formData.username });
                    } else if (error.code && error.code === 'NewPasswordRequired') {         
                       transition(PHASE.NEW_PASSWORD, { cognitoUser: error.cognitoUser });                           
                    } else {
                        processAuthError(error);
                    }
                });
```